# How to be a faster Panda with groupbys

Tags: python, performance, pandas, bigdata, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 150 million rows. Within that there are about 1 million groups I'd like to do some very simple calculations on. For example, I'd like to take some existing column `'A'` and make a new column, `'A_Percentile'` that expresses the values of '`A'` as percentile ranks, within the group. Here's a little function that does it:

```
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

def rankify(column_name,data=my_data_frame):
    f = lambda x: [percentileofscore(x, y) for y in x]
    data[column_name+'_Percentile'] = data.groupby(['Group_variable_1',
                                               'Group_variable_2'])[column_name].transform(f)
    return
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
rankify('Column_to_Rank', my_data_frame)
```

And wait for...quite a long time.

There are some obvious things I could do to speed this up (for instance, I'm sure there's a way to vectorize `[percentileofscore(x, y) for y in x]`). However, I have the feeling that there are some Pandas tricks I could be doing to speed this up immensely. Is there something I could be doing with the `groupby` logic? I thought about breaking it apart and parallelizing it, but 1. I'm not sure of a good way to do it and 2. the communication time to write out the data and read in the results seems like it would take nearly as long (perhaps I think that because of point #1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably aware, the speed of groupby operations can vary tremendously -- especially as the number of groups gets high.  Here's a really simple alternate approach that is quite a bit faster on some test datasets I tried (anywhere from 2x to 40x faster).  Usually it is faster if you can avoid user-written functions (in combination with groupby) and stick to built-in functions (which are usually cythonized):

```
In [163]: %timeit rankify('x',df)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.38 s per loop

In [164]: def rankify2(column_name,data):
     ...:     r1 = data.groupby('grp')[column_name].rank()
     ...:     r2 = data.groupby('grp')[column_name].transform('count')
     ...:     data[column_name+'_Percentile2'] = 100. * r1 / r2 

In [165]: %timeit rankify2('x',df)
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop
```

Note that my method gives ever so slightly different results (like a difference of `10e-15`) compared to `percentileofscore()`.  So if you test the results with `x == y` most will be True but some will be False, but `x.round() == y.round()` will pass.

For results above, this was my test dataset (for other cases I tried, the difference was smaller but always 2x or better speedup):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { "grp" : np.repeat( np.arange(1000), 100 ),
                     "x"   : np.random.randn(100000)           } )
```

I'm sure you could do better than that if you want.  Really all you need to do here is sort and rank.  I suspect the basic approach I took will be a good way to do it but if you did some or all of it in numpy or numba you might be able to speed it up.  Also, you could might be able to use some of pandas indexing tricks to speed things up.

Comment: Thanks! That is, in fact, phenomenally faster. The key advice seems to be to use built-in functions whenever possible. 1. Are there any other tricks/principles? 2. I find navigating the built-in functions for groupbys to be tricky and confusing. Where is there good documentation on _all the built-in functions_ for groupbys?

Comment: I don't have any other general advice besides sticking to built-ins as much as possible and use the most up to date version of pandas.  It's mostly trial and error for me, plus knowledge that you can do a lot just with ```rank``` and ```count```, which are both pretty fast.  If you browse the performance sections of the release notes, you can see when various functions were cythonized for groupby.  You can also search SO for stuff like "groupby slow", especially in combo with "large dataset" or "large number of groups".